# Buttons not working, even in newly generated activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating an android app, the project is quite large. I've spent around 3 weeks developing this application, and have numerous buttons, all working; almost all (with maybe one or two exceptions) are defined within the XML file calling the method in the class defined in the context like so:

(Toasts are pseudo)

```
android:onclick="doSomething"

public void doSomething(View view) {Toast "Hello world"};
```

the exceptions being:

```
    Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.helloWorldButton);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast"helloworld";
        }
    });
```

Now, even with newly generated basic activities; the default FAB button isn't even calling the example snackBar.

To the root of my question; Is there anything that may have happened that would result in the error message:

"Could not find method doSomething(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view"

even in newly generated activities (generated by android studio).

XML activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="eatec.cookery.StepActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_step" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="eatec.cookery.StepActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_step">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java:

```
package eatec.cookery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StepActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_step);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                helloWorldMethod();
            }
        });
    }


    public void helloWorldMethod() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: you better add your xml and activity code, so we can help you.

Comment: Added the code, like you can see; it's almost identical to the default generated basic activity. However the Toast does not show up; i'd bet money that if i were to call the helloWorldMethod from the onclick in the XML it will throw the same error.

Comment: is it a typo mistake in xml you provided, the ending tag of constraint layout above?

Comment: Yes sorry it would have been just a mistake when i was copying and pasting; they're two seperate XML files, i've seperated them for you now

Comment: you are adding a layout with width and height match parent over a fab, check it again by removing/ changing it or give elevation to fab.

Comment: I've added elevation, however I thought that 6dp was the default elevation for the floating action button. Regardless, it's still not working.

Comment: I get the error Could not find method helloWorldMethod(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton with id 'fab'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous activity used set Content instead of starting a new activity with new intent. Oops